# How to add the table td texts in progress values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have progress bars in the third column of my table. And I replace the value of progressbar from td that I commented used, and max of the progress bar from td that I commented available.

the problem of my code is with on request text. whenever i wrote this text instead of a number my code does not work and even shows an error.If you write a number instead of "one request" my code works correctly. How can I use "onrequest" as zero ?I mean i want to suppose unrequest text as 0 .

Here is my snippet :

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var children = $(this).children('td');    //get all td children of current tr
  var vals = $(children[1]).html().split('<br>');   //get an array of values by splitting on <br>
  var maxVals = $(children[0]).html().split('<br>');   //likewise get an array of max values by splitting on <br>
  var progressBars = $(this).find('progress');    // find all progress elements inside current tr.
  vals.forEach((val, index) => {     //iterate over vals array
      $(progressBars[index]).val(parseInt(val));     //use index to set val for correct progressBar
      $(progressBars[index]).prop('max', parseInt(maxVals[index]));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>on request <br/> 30</td> <!--available-->
<td>4 <br/> 5</td> <!--used-->
<td colspan="2"> 
<progress value="98" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress><br/>
<progress value="98" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20 <br/> 20</td> <!--available-->
<td>6  <br/> 5</td>  <!--used-->
<td>
<progress value="50" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress><br/>
 <progress value="50" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try using `$(progressBars[index]).prop('max', parseInt(maxVals[index] == 'on request ' ? 0 : maxVals[index]));` instead of `$(progressBars[index]).prop('max', parseInt(maxVals[index]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple if statement would do the trick:

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var children = $(this).children('td');    //get all td children of current tr
  var vals = $(children[1]).html().split('<br>');   //get an array of values by splitting on <br>
  var maxVals = $(children[0]).html().split('<br>');   //likewise get an array of max values by splitting on <br>
  var progressBars = $(this).find('progress');    // find all progress elements inside current tr.
  vals.forEach((val, index) => {     //iterate over vals array
      var value = (val.trim() === "on request") ? 0 : parseInt(val);
      var max = (maxVals[index].trim() === "on request") ? 0 : parseInt(maxVals[index]);
      $(progressBars[index]).val(val);     //use index to set val for correct progressBar
      $(progressBars[index]).prop('max', max);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>on request <br/> 30</td> <!--available-->
<td>4 <br/> 5</td> <!--used-->
<td colspan="2"> 
<progress value="98" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress><br/>
<progress value="98" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20 <br/> 20</td> <!--available-->
<td>6  <br/> 5</td>  <!--used-->
<td>
<progress value="50" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress><br/>
 <progress value="50" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i added your code but i still have an error on my code.

Comment: still my code does not work and shows Script error on snippet

Comment: I fixed mine, is it "on request" or "one request"? also I added trim to get rid of white spaces